# Can't debug newly created Windows Azure project. The Windows Azure Debugger keeps crashing in loop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-debugger

I've just downloaded Azure SDK 1.6 through Windows Platform Installer.

When I start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Windows Azure Project and try to debug it, the screen stops at this point:
[image]

And then the Windows Azure Debugger crashes over and over:

[image]

And when I hit cancel it crashes again.

My Compute Emulator diagnostics window looks like this:

[image]

When I hit cancel in the dialog the diagnostics repeats the last lines and then it crashes again. I've already tried to restart my VS and Windows with no results. I've also reinstalled the Azure SDK.

Any ideas?

Comment: A hunch, nothing more: what happens if you use a username that doesn't have an accented character? Also: try "Start without Debugging", then after the process has started, attach the debugger manually.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee thank you for your reply. I tried a different no accented user name. Didn't work. I can't find the "Run -> Start without debugging" option. Is it normal?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: in Visual Studio, Debug | Start without Debugging. You can then use Debug | Attach to Process to attach to your process if necessary; you may need to check "Show processes from all users" on to see the w3wp.exe process that hosts your services.

Comment: Sorry... theres no option to start without debugging. Is that normal?